# In-App Purchase hold game loop

Tags: in-app-purchase, game-loop

On my iPhone/iPad game app, when users touch on buy/purchase button, a dialog of in-app purchase is popping up and the whole game loop is stuck. I would like the game loop still updating while in-app purchase is processing.

Please someone point me to solution, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move your game loop to another thread until main thread is interrupted.

Comment: I didn't involve anything with Thread (single thread), is there any other way to do this? or I really have to learn Thread programming

Comment: Ok thank you jacekmigacz, it took me an hour to learn and implement simple thread, now I got my solution. for those who come up the same my situation, let see Listing 2.1 in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html